# Comparing and Sorting Values in Two Columns of a DataFrame and sort in the same row in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

**Question:**
I'm working on a Python project where I have a dataset with two columns: "Big List" and "Small List". I need to compare the values in the "Small List" column with the values in the "Big List" column and sort them accordingly. If a value from the "Small List" column is found in the "Big List" column, I want to sort the corresponding row in the "Small List" column.

For example, let's say I have the following data:

| Big List | Small List |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 20 |
| 20 | 30 |
| 30 | 60 |
| 40 | 0 |
| 50 | 0 |
| 60 | 0 |
| 20 | 0 |

In this scenario, I intend to compare each value in the "Small List" column with the values in the "Big List" column. I will then sort these values in the "Small List" in the same row where the corresponding value in the "Big List" column matches.

**What I want:**

| Big List | Small List |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 0 |
| 20 | 20 |
| 30 | 30 |
| 40 | 0 |
| 50 | 0 |
| 60 | 60 |
| 20 | 20 |

**What I've Tried:**
I've looked into using loops and conditional statements, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to efficiently compare and sort the values between these two columns.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Big List': [10, 20, 30, 40,50,60,20], 'Small List': [20,30,60]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Loop through rows and compare values
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Small List'] in df['Big List']:
        # Sort the row in the "Small List" column
        # Stuck here

df
```

Comment: Are the values in small list/big list column unique?

Comment: in "small list" yes but in "Big list" no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mask the values in Big List which do not belong to Small List

```
m = df['Big List'].isin(df['Small List'])
df['Small List'] = df['Big List'].where(m, 0)
```

---

```
   Big List  Small List
0        10           0
1        20          20
2        30          30
3        40           0
4        50           0
5        60          60
6        20          20
```